# how to program window to close with escape key

Tags: c, gtk

I've been searching all over the place to find out how to get my program to close using the escape key. Not that many people use GTK+ I assume. Also, if it's not asking too much, can some please show me how to use the Gnome developer website so I could find this stuff out on my own? Thanks. So, closing the window with escape key, here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <curses.h>

#define KEY_ESC '\033'

static GtkWidget *entry;

static gboolean kill_window(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
    return FALSE;
}

static void button_press(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    const char *text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry));
    //system("cd" text);
    //printf("%s\n", text);
    const char *text2 = "&";
    char *concatenation;
    concatenation = malloc(strlen(text)+2);
    strcpy(concatenation, text);
    strcat(concatenation, text2);
    system(concatenation); 
    gtk_main_quit();
}

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *button;
GtkWidget *button1;
GtkWidget *hbox;


gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Run");
button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Cancel");
entry = gtk_entry_new();
hbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 2);

gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Run..");

gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);
g_signal_connect(window, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(kill_window), NULL);

g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_press), NULL);

g_signal_connect(button1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(kill_window), NULL);
g_signal_connect(entry, "activate", G_CALLBACK(button_press), NULL);
g_signal_connect(button1, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(kill_window), NULL);
gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 250, 100);
gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window), TRUE);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), entry, TRUE, TRUE, 2);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), button, FALSE, FALSE, 2); 
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), button1, FALSE, FALSE, 2);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), hbox);
gtk_widget_show_all(window);

gtk_main(); 

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect to the `key_press_event` signal on the top-level window:

```
g_signal_connect(window, "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK(check_escape), NULL);
```

The `check_escape` callback will look like this:

```
#include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>
...
static gboolean check_escape(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer data)
{
  if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Escape) {
    gtk_main_quit();
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Also, you don't need the `<curses.h>` include, nor the `KEY_ESC` definition.

If your top-level window is essentially a dialog, you might consider using a `GtkDialog` instead of a `GtkWindow`. A dialog provides stock responses such as "OK" and "Cancel", with enter and escape keys invoking the expected response.

Comment: HOw do I declare GDK_Escape as a variable? Is it a struct I must make?

Comment: `GDK_Escape` is an integer value defined in `<gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>`; you shouldn't need any special declaration to get it.

Comment: My apologies. I figured out why I was getting an error with the 'GDK_Escape variable'. It is not defined in <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>. What is is however declared is GDK_KEY_Escape, which does the job. Thanks.

Comment: @user1217522 I've now updated the answer to use `GDK_KEY_Escape`, which seems to be the preferred name now. (`GDK_Escape` works for me, possibly because I'm testing with a different GTK version.)

Comment: If you need to test against multiple keys within `check_escape` you can `switch` on `event->keyval` (e.g. `switch (event->keyval) { case GDK_KEY_Escape: ...handle keypress...; break;` or instead of `break;` you can `return TRUE;` if no further processing of the keypress is required)

Answer (score 1):

For your application I would consider using GtkDialog and stock buttons rather than GtkWindow, that way you just need to test a return variable from the dialog that GTK sets when the user presses a button rather than set up any signal handlers. It also automatically sets it up so to return GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL if the dialog is cancelled and you can then destroy the window.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for this in 2024, here is an updated solution to this. As of now `Gtk.Dialog` is deprecated in GTK4 and it is suggested to use `Gtk.Window`, however you would need to implement some things like closing the window when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed. Here is an example in Vala:

```
public class MyDialog : Gtk.Window {
    public MyDialog(Gtk.Window parent, string title) {
        Object (
            title: title,
            transient_for: parent,
            modal: true,
            destroy_with_parent: true
        );
        add_binding_action(Gdk.Key.Escape, 0, "window.close", null);
    }
}
```

The relevant part is call to `add_binding_action`: here the 2nd argument `0` stands for no [modifier](https://valadoc.org/gtk4/Gdk.ModifierType.html) and the 3rd argument `window.close` is the name of the action that is defined by the [`Gtk.Window`](https://valadoc.org/gtk4/Gtk.Window.html) class.